# SQL GROUP BY error in sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT t.trade_id,
t.share_holder_id,
t.broker_id,
t.share_amount
FROM trades t
INNER JOIN share_holders sh
ON t.share_holder_id = sh.share_holder_id
INNER JOIN share_holder_shares shs
ON shs.share_holder_id = sh.share_holder_id
WHERE (t.share_amount  >50000
AND shs.amount         <0
OR t.transaction_type  = 2)
GROUP BY t.trade_id,
t.share_holder_id,
t.broker_id,
t.share_amount
HAVING t.share_amount =
(SELECT SUM(DECODE(transaction_type,1,share_amount))
FROM trades t1
WHERE t.share_id       = t1.share_id
AND t.share_holder_id  = t1.share_holder_id
AND t.transaction_time < t1.transaction_time
GROUP BY t.share_amount
) 
OR t.share_amount =
(SELECT SUM(DECODE(transaction_type,2,0-share_amount))
FROM trades t1
WHERE t.share_id       = t1.share_id
AND t.share_holder_id  = t1.share_holder_id
AND t.transaction_time < t1.transaction_time
GROUP BY t.share_amount
)
ORDER BY t.trade_id,
t.share_holder_id,
t.broker_id ;
```

I am getting a not a group by error in the second sub query. Cant understand how to solve it. The aim of the query is to find all brokers who allowed share holders to buy or sell more than 50,000 shares per trade or to sell shares they didnt own.

Comment: a sqlfiddle should be very usefull!

Comment: What is the use of `GROUP BY t.share_amount`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I am actually confused what group by to put in as the others will give an error of too many values

Comment: Do you need `GROUP BY`? If yes, why?

Comment: In the sub query i dont need a group by. The point of the sub query is just to check the share_amount. But the error persists even if i take off he group by

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of your `having` subqueries:

```
(SELECT SUM(DECODE(transaction_type,1,share_amount))
FROM trades t1
WHERE t.share_id       = t1.share_id
AND t.share_holder_id  = t1.share_holder_id
AND t.transaction_time < t1.transaction_time
GROUP BY t.share_amount
)
```

The `having` clause is processed *after* the `group by`.  So, in the `having` clause, you can have the columns used for aggregation (`t.trade_id`, `t.share_holder_id`, `t.broker_id`, `t.share_amount`) or other columns within aggregation functions (such as `max(t.share_id)`).

I notice that you are making a comparison to a column used for aggregation.  You can fix the syntax error by moving the logic into a `where` clause (before the `group by`).  That fixes the syntax problem; I'm not sure if it is the result you are looking for.